# Comprehensive Guide for Ph.D. thesis in Mathematics?

Tags: phd, thesis, mathematics, reference-request

Could any one recommend some comprehensive guide (online version preferred) for writing a Ph.D. thesis in Mathematics?

I did some google search but there are too many results and it is difficult to decide which one to read. Here I am not asking anyone to write such a guide for me (otherwise this question will be too broad and thus not suitable here); instead, I would appreciate if anyone could make some recommendations of those existing references.

Comment: Nicholas Higham's "Handbook of writing for the mathematical sciences" has a chapter specifically on theses.

Comment: Thanks @DavidKetcheson! By the way, my question was down-voted. Is it not suitable here?

Comment: Some users might consider an open-ended request for resources as unsuitable, since there are many possible answers and none are objectively more correct than others (see the [help/dont-ask]). But it's just one down vote and there are currently no votes to close, so it's a little premature to conclude that the community considers the question unsuitable - we just know that *one* person does.

Comment: SIAM's style manual is a very useful source on writing mathematics in general and using LaTeX in particular.  http://www.siam.org/journals/pdf/stylemanual.pdf

Answer (score 4):

It could also be helpful to check [this](http://maths.york.ac.uk/www/ResearchWriting) and [this](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/advice/how-to-write-a-thesis.html) short guides and the books by Steven G. Krantz, in particular

- [A Mathematician's Survival Guide: Graduate School and Early Career Development](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSCM)
- [A Primer of Mathematical Writing](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=pmw)

The first one contains subsection 4.6 which deals specifically with writing a thesis, the second one is on mathematical writing in general but it does not really deal with the theses *per se*.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://people.bath.ac.uk/mamamf/talks/awayday2012.pdf) is the best guide I have ever encountered.

It is neither too broad nor too narrow as a guide.
Moreover, it does not contain the policies of a specific university (you should number the figures that way and write equations this way etc.)

The persentation explains how should the overall *feeling* of a thesis be, and nothing more.

I also find [this](http://people.kmi.open.ac.uk/stefan/thesis-writing.pdf) manuscript very useful. However, some subsections are incomplete and marked as *[todo]*.

Comment: Both of your links point to the same file. Is it the way you intended it to be?

Comment: @just-learning It is my mistake. Corrected it now. Thanks for your notice.